# Use Name vs DeveloperName for RecordType?

Tags: apex, soql, record-type

What is best practice for working with RecordType in Apex (using DeveloperName)? Why should I use SOQL with DeveloperName if I can do it without query using regular name:

```
Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('xxx').getRecordTypeId();
```

vs

```
[SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE DeveloperName ='xxx'].Id;
```

Both Name and DeveloperName are changed when editing Name.

Comment: if you are worried about soql, use a lazy loading utility class that retrieves all recordtypes into a static map for subsequent lookup via a Util method. This way, only one soql is burned and only when needed

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually, that is not quite true. `Name` is the field that the user sees when they choose it in the screen (or on the Page Layout). `Developer Name` is the API name for the record.

This is very similar to the way the `Label` and the `API Name` work for fields and object.

Because of this, it is best practice to always use `Developer Name`, since it is less likely to change (and it is unique in the object). As a dev, you can easily rename the `Name` to adjust to changing business requirements, but need not rename the `Developer Name` and leave your code working just fine.

Per the Docs:

**Developer Name**

> Required. The unique name of the object in the API. This name can contain only underscores and alphanumeric characters, and must be unique in your org. It must begin with a letter, not include spaces, not end with an underscore, and not contain two consecutive underscores. In managed packages, this field prevents naming conflicts on package installations. With this field, a developer can change the object’s name in a managed package and the changes are reflected in a subscriber’s organization. Label is Record Type Name.

**Name**

> Required. Label of the record type in the user interface. Limit: 80 characters. Label is Record Type Label.

You can read the entire explanation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_recordtype.htm), in SFDC documentation.

Comment: So I believe Salesforce has to add ability to get Id by DeveloperName without query. Because sometimes extra query can be serious issue.

Comment: You could use `getRecordTypeInfos();` and iterate. No new soql queries needed.

Comment: But there is no DeveloperName in RecordTypeInfo class

Comment: Huh, so right you are. Very strange indeed. I hope this gets remedied soon.

Comment: The cool thing about RecordType.Name is: Account myAccount = new Account( Name="TestAccount", RecordType = new RecordType(Name="myRecordTypeName)); insert myAccount

Answer (score 7):

Use a unique identifier wherever possible to query for vital configuration data. In this case, `DeveloperName` is unique, where `Name` is not. So there is a clear and compelling case to use the former.

Answer (score 6):

Developer name remains static, label can be changed to a different value.

Best practice is to always use developer name to get recordtype Id.

Answer (score 4):

Another reason to use the `DeveloperName` is that the `Name` is subject to translation and could generate problems if your org has user in multiple locales

Answer (score 1):

Just writing this for anybody who comes through one of the search engines: Salesforce recently released the `getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName()` function. So you can write:

```
Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('xxx').getRecordTypeId();
```

With xxx beeing the save Developer Name (as other answers already pointed out). More Information here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm

Comment: Before you go charging down this path waving your flags and jumping for joy read this; https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/234024/getrecordtypeinfosbydevelopername-doesnt-work-with-duplicate-developer-names