# How to create SOQL query for List<RecordType>

Tags: apex, unit-test

So I have this SOQL query in the apex test class.

`List<RecordType> RecordTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'FAQ']`

This `RecordType` is a part of some `XYZ` Object. So for each test method of our test class, we are creating one sample record of the `FAQ` type. The String FAQ present in that SOQL query is repeated in every test method So I just want to replace this string `FAQ` with a constant to avoid code quality issues, but I am getting an error every time I try to replace it. Can you please tell me how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Initially the initial line need to be corrected as below.

```
List<RecordType> recordTypes= [Select Id from RecordType where Name='FAQ'];
```

As the SOQL query will give you the List of Sobject of type RecordType.

Coming to your question you need to define the constant and use that in the where condition as below.

```
static final String  str='FAQ';
List<RecordType> recordTypes= [Select Id from RecordType where Name=:str];
system.debug('record'+recordTypes);
```

You can even get the recordtypeid without using SOQL as below.

```
Id clinicRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.**Account**.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('FAQ').getRecordTypeId();
```

Comment: so instead of Account over there, we need to mention the object in which are working on right?

Comment: Yes @Aishwarya you are correct. Instead of Account you have to replace the Object name of the recordtype

Answer (score 1):

1. As a best practice, it's not recommended to rely on the `RecordType.Name` field value. Prefer `RecordType.DeveloperName`. Please take a look at [Use Name vs DeveloperName for RecordType?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164188/use-name-vs-developername-for-recordtype)
2. If you want to store some `RecordTypeId` and share this value in a test context, you may want to create some separate `TestConstants` apex class to keep such commonly used constants and to expose a `XYZ_RECORDTYPE_ID_FAQ` `RecordTypeId` as a field of this class.

Using [DescribeSObjectResult.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName) approach is preferable, bacause you don't need to execute unnecessary extra SOQL queries, and because the result of the `Schema.SObjectType` is cached:

```
@IsTest
public class TestConstants {

   public static final Id XYZ_RECORDTYPE_ID_FAQ = Schema.SObjectType.XYZ__c
        .getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName()
        .get('FAQ_RecordTypeDeveloperName')
        .getRecordTypeId();
}
```

You may also want to expose the `XyzRecordTypeIdFaq` as a getter to optimize the performance of the `TestConstants` class static initialization, in order to lazy load the value only on demand. It is not necessary to make this property lazy, because the schema result is cached.